# How to make Min/MaxValueValidator work with Django's DecimalField?

Tags: python, django, validation, decimal

A strange failure seems to occur in Django 2.1.2 (Python 3.7.0):

```
from django.db.models import DecimalField
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
f = DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(10), MaxValueValidator(20)])
```

This is the expected behavior:

```
>>> f.clean(15, model_instance=None)
Decimal('15')
>>> f.clean('15', model_instance=None)
Decimal('15')
```

But this doesn't work:

```
>>> f.clean(5, model_instance=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/.../anaconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 632, in clean
    self.run_validators(value)
  File "/Users/.../anaconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 591, in run_validators
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: <exception str() failed>
```

Same error for:

```
>>> f.clean('5', model_instance=None)
>>> f.clean(25, model_instance=None)
```

What am I doing wrong?

NB: I know how to validate this field manually in the ModelForm, but I would prefer to avoid the workaround. I have checked some related answers with no success:

- [DecimalField Validation in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40322802/decimalfield-validation-in-django)
- [MinValueValidator not working on DecimalField in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578193/minvaluevalidator-not-working-on-decimalfield-in-django)
- [Django strange DecimalField validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376693/django-strange-decimalfield-validation)

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't it working fine? You set minValueValidator to 10, and maxValueValidator to 20, if you enter a number n<10 or n>20 it raises an exception, else it returns a decimal.